# Why the nested stream not processing map or filter functions when there is close() in the end

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-11

I have a nested stream that I am using in order to process some data related to a requirement

```
final Map<String, Long> productModelQuantityReturnedMap = new HashMap<>();

sampleList.stream()
          .map(sampleModel -> {
              sampleModel.getEntries()
                         .stream()
                         .filter(entryModel -> Objects.nonNull(entryModel.getOrderEntry()))
                         .map(returnEntryModel -> {
                            sampleMap.put(
                              key,
                              val);
                            return null;
                      }).close();
              return null;
        }).close();
```

Yeah am aware that using for each or for would be ideal but yeah. I wanted to extend this to a parallel thread going forward since it has a lot of data points that don't depend on each other.

Although it says stream or the parallel stream will wait until the inner part is done this goes directly to the `close()` of the outer stream which I don't understand why.

Can someone please help me on finding the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` and `filter` are intermediate operations. A stream is not processed unless a terminal operation is invoked. Here in your code you are not invoking any terminal operation so that the stream is processed. Since `close` is **not** a terminal operation, it does not process the stream. It just resets everything and ends the stream. You could refer `AbstractPipeline` to see the source code for `close`. Only thing that is executed is the code, if any, which was passed using the `onClose` method. (i.e If you used `onClose` on the stream, `stream().onClose(() -> myCloseAction())....`).

Also, `close` is not really required in the code which you have posted. As you mentioned in the question itself, you could use `forEach`. It definitely works with parallel streams as well ([forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)). Only thing is that your code seems to be updating a map. Make sure that is a concurrent map. Or it is much better to use `toMap` or `toConcurrentMap` from the `Collectors` class instead of putting elements inside a map using `forEach`.

Comment: Or use the Stream API like intended, e.g. `Map<String, Long> productModelQuantityReturnedMap = sampleList.stream()
 .flatMap(sampleModel -> sampleModel.getEntries().stream())
 .filter(entryModel -> entryModel.getOrderEntry() != null)
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> …, e -> …));` instead of trying to apply imperative programming paradigms. It’s not clear what to fill in for the last functions, because the code of the question has never seen a compiler.